# Private data collection vs encryption

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, access-control

I have a question regarding the theory behind the concept of private data collection in Hyperledger Fabric.
How the fabric implement it ? I mean is it considered a form of access control method ? Or based on some type of encryption? Or via gossip protocol?

Could any one explain ?

Thank you for the answers, however you stated that private data collection is achieving data privacy on organization  level, then how to protect privacy on user level?

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger fabric documentation https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/private-data/private-data.html#what-is-a-private-data-collection captures details on the privacy, how it is achieved. Please refer here.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Read https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/private-data/private-data.html, as Param recommends.

Take into account that Private Data provides privacy at organization level, not at user level. If you want end-to-end data privacy at user level, you must implement yourself at application level.

Basically, private data is distributed via gossip protocol (the protocol that synchronizes the ledgers) in a way it can be only read by the peers that belong to the authorized organizations. Each peer maintains a private state per channel with the private data of its organization. The chain of the ledger basically stores a hash of every private transaction to provide integrity, while not disclosing the writesets and readsets.

Regarding the chaincode, https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/private_data_tutorial.html can be useful.

Comment: Well understood, but how to implement in user level,